# If an Ideal I is not finitely generated and then I+(a) is not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finitely-generated

Suppose of have a ideal $I\subset R$ that is not finitely generated.
Then is it the case that the ideal $I+(a)$  is also not finitely generated.

I was thinking to assume the contradiction that it is finitely generated, then to take $(I +(a))/(a)$ which will again be finitely generated.

This shows that I is finitely generated which is a contradiction.

Comment: $(I+(a))/(a)$ is not always isomorphic to $I$. For example, consider $a=1$.

Comment: Take $a=1$. More generally, take a non-finitely generated maximal ideal and any $a$ not in $I$.

Comment: For example, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, $ I=(2,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$, and $(a)=(3)$. Then $I$ is not finitely generated, but $I+(a)=R=(1)$ is principal.

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin this clarifies much of my thinking

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Now what's an example where $I + (a) \ne R$? :)

Comment: Just take the example I gave you, take another ring $R'$, and look at $I\times\{0\}$ as an ideal of $R\times R'$, and $(a,0)$. For instance, $(\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots])\times\mathbb{Z}$, the ideal $I=\bigl( (2,0),(x_1,0),\ldots,(x_n,0),\ldots)\bigr)$, and $a=(3,0)$. Then $I+(a) = R\times\{0\}$, which is generated by $(1,0)$.

Comment: @math54321 See previous comment. I mistakenly did not ping you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's a fine way to extend to the non-unit case. Another way I was thinking: there are non-Noetherian local rings where the maximal ideal is principal

Comment: @math54321 There are examples of non-descrete valuation rings whose maximal ideal is principal. They are local and non-noetherian since a noetherian valuation ring must be a DVR.

Comment: A common feature in these examples is that $I + (a)$ is principal. So one may search for an example where $I + (a)$ is not principal, but still finitely generated - I claim that one can find a subring $R \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ (which e.g. eliminates @Arturo's products) for which this is true